# How to tell if a Window Store app is sandboxed?

Tags: windows-10, sandbox

There are lots of articles claiming apps on the Windows Store are sandboxed I maybe that used to be true but that seems clearly false with apps like [Python](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/python-38/9mssztt1n39l?cid=msft_web_chart&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) or [Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) or [Norton Security](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/norton-security/9nkk9hhb8hhf?cid=msft_web_chart&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) on the store.

Are Window Store apps still sandboxed? Are some not? How I can tell which are and which are not?

Comment: AFAIK, all Windows UWP apps are sandboxed within `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps`, with different apps granted different ACL permissions depending on the access they require.

Comment: While UWP applications are installed in that directory, UWP applications still have access to specific user directories.  This means a Python script that does something malicious, to those files, could indeed be ran through the UWP Python application.  They are not sandboxed in the sense of an application ran through Windows Sandbox is prevented access to your user files, unless you specifically allow it of course.  UWP applications are ran with the lowest permissions possible, are only allowed to read specific directories, but they certainly have access to your actual user files.

Comment: "All Windows Store apps are tightly sandboxed">>>>>>>https://labs.sogeti.com/windows-store-apps-live-sandbox/

Comment: @Moab, that aritcle is old and clearly out of date.

Comment: So why would microsoft change this policy? They are still all sandboxed.

Comment: Probably because [devs complained](https://www.howtogeek.com/243559/why-desktop-apps-arent-available-in-the-windows-store-yet/)?

Comment: If you dig deeper in the store I found where it says any app listed as "Access all your files, peripheral devices, apps, programs, and registry" means [there is no sandbox for the app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10557/windows-10-app-permissions).

Answer (score 4):

Although at one point in time Windows Store apps were maybe sandboxed that requirement has clearly been removed

Windows Store Apps are clearly no longer sandboxed. You can tell by looking under "Additional information" near the bottom of each app in the store.

Examples:

[WhatsApp](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/whatsapp-desktop/9nksqgp7f2nh?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

> This app can
>   Access all your files, peripheral devices, apps, programs and registry

[Facebook](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/messenger/9wzdncrf0083?cid=msft_web_chart&activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

> This app can
>   Access all your files, peripheral devices, apps, programs and registry
>   Access your Internet connection

[Norton Security](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/norton-security/9nkk9hhb8hhf?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

> This app can
>   Access all your files, peripheral devices, apps, programs and registry
>   Use your location
>   Scan and connect to WiFi networks
>   Access your Internet connection
>   Use the software and hardware certificates available on your device
>   Access VPN features
>   Close themselves and their own windows, and delay the closing of their app
>   Gather information about other apps

I'm not here to start a platform war. I'm on a Windows 10 PC as I write this. But unforunately because Windows Store Apps are not sandboxed they are not safe to install.

You can compare this to MacOS App Store app which, AFAIK, it's safe to run any app from the Mac App Store. They are entirely sandboxed and there are no automatic permissions given to an any app. If an app wants to access something outside the sandbox it has to ask the user for permission so you can be sure (barring OS bugs) that when you download the app, it won't be able to read your files, access your camera, use your mic, look into other apps, capture the screen, etc.

Conversly, that's not to be true with the Windows App store. Some apps get immediate permission to read all files on the hard drive, access all devices, etc...

For example, if I download the [WhatsApp App](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/whatsapp-desktop/id1147396723?mt=12) from the Mac App Store for MacOS I'm assured the app **can not** reach outside its sandbox.

Unforunately the [Windows Store version of the same App](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/whatsapp-desktop/9nksqgp7f2nh?activetab=pivot:overviewtab), based on what is says on the store "This app can Access all your files, peripheral devices, apps, programs and registry" has no sandbox.

Following [the link there](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10557/windows-10-app-permissions) Microsoft explains that "Access all your files, preipherial devices, apps, programs and registry" means:

> Access all your files, peripheral devices, apps, programs, and registry: The app has the ability to read or write to all your files (including documents, pictures, and music) and registry settings, which allows the app to make changes to your computer and settings. It can use any peripheral devices that are either attached or part of your device (such as cameras, microphones, or printers) without notifying you. It also has access to your location, and can use platform features, such as  location history, app diagnostics, and more, which are denied to most Store apps. **You can't control most of the permissions for this app in Settings > Privacy.**

In other words, no sandbox

Comment: Except those listings indicate that there appears to _be_ a sandbox, just that the permissions are auto-granted on install.  That is, the app has declared it won't work **at all** without those permissions, and the user is expected to check the list and not install if they don't agree with the granted permissions.

Comment: Those permission amount to no sandbox.

Comment: ... and if you granted all those permissions to a Mac app then there "wouldn't be a sandbox"?  What I'm getting at is that the windows store is just front-loading all the necessary permissions.

Comment: The difference is I can choose to not grant those permissions on Mac. I can't on Windows. Updated the answer where Microsoft makes this clear. Note My goal was to install an app I have on Mac on Windows. On Mac I can be mostly sure the app can't do things I don't want it too. On Windows I was hoping for the same. IIRC when the Windows Store started it was similar to Mac in that apps got no permissions. That has clearly changed. Most famous apps install with "Access all your files, peripheral devices, apps, programs, and registry" which is just a another way to say "this app not sandboxed".